# How to get the uploaded file names as an JSON array in JQuery

Tags: arrays, file, upload

I am using multiple file upload,

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
```

How to get the uploaded file names as an JSON array in JQuery.
I need to pass array as AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for file upload using jquery ajax.
HTML and jQuery Code:

`<form name="fileupload" id="fileupload" onsubmit="return submitFile()">
                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function submitFile() {
                    var formData = new FormData($("#fileupload")[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax-upload.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: "json",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            $(response.filenames).each(function(index, value){
                                console.log("File Name " + value);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            </script>`

Here is the php code to upload multiple files.

`$filenames = array();
for ($cnt = 0; $cnt < count($_FILES['files']["name"]); $cnt++) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']["tmp_name"][$cnt], "images/" . $_FILES['files']["name"][$cnt])) {
        $filenames[] = $_FILES['files']["name"][$cnt];
    }
}
echo json_encode(array("filenames" => $filenames));`